# JQuery selector to both show() and hide()

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideButton').click(function(){
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').hide();
    });
});
```

In the above code snippet, suppose I want to add both the code

1. for show() function to show the content and
2. for hide() function to hide the content.

is it possible?

Comment: You mean, toggling between show and hide?

Comment: You want to show and hide the content at the same time?

Comment: as le chiffre says in casino royale: why not?

Comment: @Felix: Perhaps he wants an epilepsy-inducing `<blink>` tag!

Comment: yes man i want to toggling between show and hide
i have done but it's not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideButton').click(function(){
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').toggle();
           //http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/slicker-show-and-hide
         or 
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').slideToggle("slow");
         //http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/
    });
});
```

Comment: i have to check for that its working for me will get back to you if find solid reason for this

Comment: hi! pranay, i had done some mistake in id. that's y it's not working. now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideButton').click(function(){
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideButton').click(function(){
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').toggle();
    });
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle2

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hideButton').click(function(){
         $('#disclaimer,#clock').toggle();
    });
});
```